# Angular2 - ngOnDestroy() not called on similar route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have an Angular2 app with a route like this:

```
{
  path: '',
  component: ContentComponent,
  children: [
    {
      path: 'folder/:folderId',
      resolve: {              
        currentFolder: CurrentFolderResolver,
      },
      children: [
        {
          path: '',
          resolve: {
            folderStructure: FolderStructureResolve,
          },
          component: FolderOverviewComponent,
        },
        {
          path: 'users',
          component: UsersComponent,
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

When navigating from a route like */folder/123* to */folder/456*, Angular will not trigger `ngOnDestroy()` in the `FolderOverviewComponent`. Navigating to */folder/456/users* will do.

In other words, it seems like Angular does not destroy the component if the route does not change (ignoring the dynamic part of *:folderId*). This seems reasonable, nevertheless I need to clean up things in `ngOnDestroy()`.

Can I configure Routes to call destroy each time I navigate to a new route (i.e. with a different parameter)?

Answer (score 7):

That's by design. If only a route parameter changes which leads to the same route being used, the component is not destroyed and recreated but reused.

You can subscribe to `params` changes to be able to execute code when the route was changed:

```
constructor(router: ActivatedRoute) {
  router.params.subscribe(param => routeChanged(param['folderId']));
}
```

There are plans to provide more flexibility in the future, but currently that's the way to go.

See also https://angular.io/guide/router#activated-route-in-action

Comment: Could I request a bit more detail, or some additional resources? A2 docs only mention this in passing and I am not able to find details on this anywhere else. All of the answers that show up in google are for the old router, before modules.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7757#issuecomment-236737846 I don't know about other docs.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Has there been a better solution to this since this question?

Comment: You can search for `RouteReuseStrategy`, it might offer something for you.

Comment: Note 2018/03/01:  The type of router must be ActivatedRoute. Router doesn't have any property params

Comment: @Paradise228 This answer is quite old. This was an entirely different router back then. I think it was May 2017 when they came up with a new router. I'll update the question later when I have more time. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: @Paradise228 just saw you suggested an edit. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Hi @GünterZöchbauer thanks for the reply, so the default behave from Router nav. is whenever the URL from the same component gets updated (i.e.: foo/:arg1 to foo/:arg1/:arg2) the component gets destroyed ?