# How to push data into array in Angular 2 when using similar route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

So far, I haven't found a simple example of how to push data into an array in Angular 2. In AngularJs it was easy ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/7n8NR/3/)), but I'm struggling for it in Angular 2, maybe because I'm using router and I don't know how to configure it (I was following the angular [heroes example](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5)).

What I want to do, the whole solution:

**app.module.ts:**

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { ProductsService } from '../services/ProductsService';


import { AppComponent } from "./components/app";
import { Products } from "./components/products";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            {
                path: 'products/:class_id/:type_id',
                component: Products
            }
        ], { useHash: true })
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
        Products
    ],
    providers: [
        ProductsService
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**AppComponent.ts**

```
import { Component} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    template: `<div>
                <a [routerLink]="['/products', 1, 1]">Products-1</a>
                <a [routerLink]="['/products', 2, 2]">Products-2</a>
               </div>`
})
export class AppComponent{}
```

**ProductsService.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class ProductsService {

    private headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getProducts(class_id: string, type_id: string, index: number, numberOfObjectsPerPage: number): Promise<any> {
        return this.http.get('Home/GetProducts?pageIndex=' + index +'&classId=' + class_id + '&typeId=' + type_id)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json() as any)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
        console.error('An error occurred', error); // for demo purposes only
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
}
```

**Product.ts**

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

import { ProductsService } from '../../services/ProductsService';
import { Product } from '../../common/models/Product';

@Component({
    selector: 'products',
    templateUrl: 'Products.html',
})
export class Products implements OnInit {
    products: Array<Product> = [];
    numberOfObjectsPerPage: number = 10;
    index: number = 0;
    constructor(
        private productsService: ProductsService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute
    ) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.loadProducts();
    }

    loadProducts():void{
        this.route.paramMap
            .switchMap((params: ParamMap) =>
                this.productsService.getProducts(params.get('class_id'), params.get('type_id'), this.index, this.numberOfObjectsPerPage))
            .subscribe(products => {
                this.products = products;
        });
    }

    showMore():void{
        this.index++;
        this.loadProducts();
    }
}
```

**Products.html:**

```
<div class="product" *ngFor="let product of products;">
  {{ product.name }}
</div>
<button (click)="showMore()">Show more</button>
```

So, what is the problem here: if I go to `Products-1` I get 10 products, which is obvious, but if I press `Show more` then the first 10 products are removed and another 10 are shown - which again is obvious, so to avoid this and keep the first 10 and load 10 more, I replaced `Product.ts -> this.products = products;` to:

```
 for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
  this.products.push(products[i]);
 }
```

Another problem appears now: when I go to `Product-2`, the products from `Products-1` are shown along with the products of `Product-2`, so to avoid this, I added this two lines into the `Product.ts constructor:`

```
constructor(private productsService: ProductsService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
        route.paramMap.subscribe(params => this.products = []);
        route.paramMap.subscribe(params => this.index = 0);
}
```

Now, everything works just fine except: when I go from `Products-1` to `Products-2` and load more products, and after that return to `Products-1`, I can see in my network tab that multiple requests of same type are being send to my server.

So my questions are:

1. Is there a better way to push data when using routing, and avoid to reset the parameters in the constructor ?
2. If the pushing into the array is okay, and if it is okay to reset the parameters in the constructor, then, how to avoid multiple requests when going from one route to another ?

Comment: subscribing to routeParams you get the array data?

Comment: yes, that's correct

Comment: Do have a solution for this or need more help

Comment: Yes, I still need some help, see my comment under Melchia's anwser

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**There are several things that I would add/change in `product.ts`:**

1. Add those properties under your `index: number = 0;` property:

   ```
   class_id: string;  
   type_id: string;
   ```
2. Remove `route.paramMap.subscribe` from the `constructor`
3. `ngOnInit`, should look like this:

   ```
   ngOnInit(): void {
     this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
       this.products = [];
       this.index = 0;
       this.type_id = params.get('type_id');
       this.class_id = params.get('class_id');
       this.loadProducts();
     });   
   }
   ```
4. And finally, `loadProducts()`:

   ```
   loadProducts(): void {
     this.productsService.getProducts(this.class_id, this.type_id, this.index, this.numberOfObjectsPerPage).then(
       productArray => {
            this.products = this.products.concat(productArray);
       })
   }
   ```

Comment: +1, but the `for`-loop could be replaced by `this.products = this.products.concat(productArray);`, which ensures that a new reference is created.

Comment: Yes, I agree, I was just following his logic, but I'll update the answer now

Answer (score 0):

in **Product.ts**:

```
   import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
    import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
    import { ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
    import * as $ from 'jquery';

    import { ProductsService } from '../../services/ProductsService';
    import { Product } from '../../common/models/Product';

    @Component({
        selector: 'products',
        templateUrl: 'Products.html',
    })
    export class Products implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
        subscribe:any;
        products: Array<Product> = [];
        numberOfObjectsPerPage: number = 10;
        index: number = 0;
        constructor(
            private productsService: ProductsService,
            private route: ActivatedRoute
        ) {}

        ngOnInit(): void {
            this.loadProducts();
        }

        loadProducts():void{
            this.subscribe=this.route.paramMap
                .switchMap((params: ParamMap) =>
                    this.productsService.getProducts(params.get('class_id'), params.get('type_id'), this.index, this.numberOfObjectsPerPage))
                .subscribe(products => {
                    this.products = this.products.concat(products);
            });
        }

        showMore():void{
            this.index++;
            this.loadProducts();
        }
        ngOnDestroy():void{
            this.subscribe.unsubscribe();
}

    }
```

Basically use **unsubcribe** method;

Comment: still nothing, I figured out that this happens because I'm using the same route just with different parameters, and angular is not calling the `destroy` because he thinks he is on the same route all the time, just the service is called: `getProducts(..)`, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40678321/angular2-ngondestroy-not-called-on-similar-route

but this is not helpful either, so I'm still stuck on this..